# Excel 2010: #DIV/0! Error while cell referencing "<A1" in AVERAGEIF formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have 2 sheets

**`Sheet A`**

```
Column A          Column B                           Column C

From                To                  Avg. Forex Rate between these 2 dates

1 April 2013       25 June 2013

26 June 2013       27 July 2013

29 Ocotober 2013   31 March 2013
```

**`Sheet B`-Exchange Rates during the year**

```
   Column A          Column B
Date         Exchange Rate
1 April          60.2
2 April          63.5
3 April          64.5
.
.
.
31st March       60.1
```

I am trying to find out the Average Exchange rates between 2 dates(as in Sheet A) using the `Averageif` formula

The formula I am Applying is

```
=AVERAGEIF('Sheet B'!A1:A365,AND(">B1","<C1"),'Sheet B'!B1:B365)
```

However,I get the `#DIV/0!` Error.

After much research and troubleshooting I found out,that even if i Don't use the `AND` function in the above forumula I still get the #DIV/0! Error.

After some more research I found out,that

If we give a `Cell reference` in the formula Averageif ,i.e. `">B1"` ,we get the error.

If we put a `manual` number, i.e. `">41365"` we do not get the error.

Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is done by design and is not a bug. A cell reference inside a string will not evaluate literally. One way to get around this would be to write as

```
">"&B1
```

I think you're also going to have issues using the `AND` function with the second argument. Instead, use `AVERAGEIFS` which allows you to use multiple conditions for determining whether values should be included in the average. So your formula would be something like

```
=AVERAGEIFS('Sheet B'!B1:B365,'Sheet B'!A1:A365,">"&B1,'Sheet B'!A1:A365,"<"&C1)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!
Sorry for the word bug...my bad.